# Error when using animate package in beamer: Undefined control sequence: \sys_if_engine_pdftex

Tags: beamer, animate

I am attempting to use the animate package in beamer. Whenever the \usepackage statement is included, I get this:

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.141 \sys_if_engine_pdftex:T
                             {
?

I can't find any information on what this might be or how to fix it. Help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably have an outdated version of `expl3`. Do a thorough update of MiKTeX

Comment: OK, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: The `\sys_if_engine_...` functions have been added in the version released on 2015-09-07.

Comment: That probably explains it then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software and was solved with an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thorough update of MiKTeX, as recommended by egreg, fixed the problem. Thanks, egreg!